# How to read specific ascii format in R

Tags: r, ascii

I have an ascii file that has the following format:

```
  4 3 2 
 0.00 0.00 
 0.00
 0.00 0.00 
 0.00
 0.00 0.00 
 0.00
 0.00 0.00 
 0.00
 1.00 1.00
 1.00 
 1.00 1.00
 1.00
 1.00 1.00
 1.00
 1.00 1.00
 1.00
```

The first line (4 3 2) is the header. Number 2 represent the numbers of groups in the file (in this case two groups: first with all zero and the second with all one).
Each group consist of 4 sub-groups of three values (two on the first row and one on the next line).

I would like to read such a file in a way that 4 represent the number of columns and 3 the number of rows of a matrix or something that I can use with `filled.contour`, keeping also the two sub-groups separated (different `factor`).

I'm trying to do this using the `read.fwf` function, but I'm facing some difficulties while trying to specify the `widths` option. The columns are not allocated in the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `scan`   here, and use the header row to create the right matrix:

```
text <- ' 4 3 2 
 0.00 0.00 
 0.00
 0.00 0.00 
 0.00
 0.00 0.00 
 0.00
 0.00 0.00 
 0.00
 1.00 1.00
 1.00 
 1.00 1.00
 1.00
 1.00 1.00
 1.00
 1.00 1.00
 1.00'
dd <- scan(textConnection(text))
matrix(dd[-c(1:3)],ncol=dd[1],nrow=dd[2]*dd[3],byrow=TRUE)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0
[4,]    1    1    1    1
[5,]    1    1    1    1
[6,]    1    1    1    1
```